# Checking number of elements in Python's `Counter`

Tags: python, collections, counter

Python 2.7/3.1 introduced the awesome `collections.Counter`.

My question: How do I count how many "element appearances" a counter has?

I want this:

```
len(list(counter.elements()))
```

But shorter.

Comment: I raised the subject on Python-ideas and Raymond Hettinger said a `Counter.elements_count()` method might be added. Python issue: http://bugs.python.org/issue11733

Comment: This idea was rejected but the issue raised looks slightly different from what the OT is asking about.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A more efficient solution is to sum up the counts (values) of each element:

```
sum(counter.values())
```

In Python **3.x**, [`values()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.values) returns a [view object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects) of the dict's values.

In Python **2.x**, [`values()`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#dict.values) returned ***an actual list***. To avoid creating a new list with Python 2.x, use [`itervalues()`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#dict.itervalues) instead:

```
sum(counter.itervalues())
```

Comment: No, there is none.  `Counter` does not keep track of this information.  At least summing the counts is much more efficient than `len(list(counter.elements()))`.

Comment: This is (a) more efficient and (b) more succinct than my original method, but it's still ugly. If there's no better way, I suggest that there should be a `Counter.elements_count()` method.

Comment: @cool-RR: Just derive from `Counter` and add that method.  Making it O(1) is cumbersome though -- you would basically need to rewrite the whole `Counter` class.

Comment: I think Python-ideas is the way to go.

Comment: @cool-RR: Well, I was assuming you just want to get the job done :)

Comment: Why would you want to update the total sum every time a item is added, that would just make the whole class slower. Doing `sum` once in the end is actually faster.

Comment: @Jochen: Your point is of course true if you only want to know the number of elements once.  If you frequently update a very large `Counter` instance and want to know the number of elements after each update, the situation might be different.